# php - Insert an array inside a multidimensionnal array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, insert

I have a multidimensional array where I want to insert an other array inside it with a var array.

My aim is to insert some element array with if statement. In fact I want to build a kind of conditionnal array.

Here an example

```
$inserted_array[] = array( 
    'name' => 'name',
    'desc' => 'a description',
    'id' => 'an id',
    'type' => 'image',
    'std' => '',
);
$inserted_array[] = array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'desc' => 'a description',
    'id' => 'an id',
    'type' => 'image',
    'std' => '',
);

$main_arrays[] = array(
    'id'    => '1234',
    'title' => 'a title',
    'icon'  => 'icon-1',
    'fields' => array(
        array( 
            'name' => 'name',
            'desc' => 'a description',
            'id' => 'an id',
            'type' => 'image',
            'std' => '',
        ),
        //$inserted_array here for example
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'desc' => 'a description',
            'id' => 'an id',
            'type' => 'image',
            'std' => '',
        ),
    )
);
```

How can I do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert the  `$inserted_array` into `$main_arrays[]['fields]`  at a given `$position`

You can achieve it by using [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function

```
array_splice($main_arrays[$index]['fields'], $position, 0, $inserted_array);
```

`$index` being the `$main_arrays` index in wich you want to insert the `$inserted_array`

`$position` being the position wich at you want to insert you're array

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to choose the place where to insert the array, this my main problem. By the way, there is a typo (fields) in your answer.

Comment: I found the php function that I need: array_splice.

Comment: @freaky I didn't understood your question well, just edited it with array_splice if it can help someone :)

Answer (score -1):

i belive what you want is:

```
$mainID = 1234;
$main_arrays[$mainID] = array(
    'title' => 'a title',
    'icon'  => 'icon-1',
    'fields' => array()
);

$main_arrays[$mainID]["fields"][] = array( 
    'name' => 'nameA',
    'desc' => 'a description',
    'id' => 'an id',
    'type' => 'image',
    'std' => '',
);


$main_arrays[$mainID]["fields"][] = array(
    'name' => 'nameB',
    'desc' => 'a description',
    'id' => 'an id',
    'type' => 'image',
    'std' => '',
);


foreach($main_arrays as $id => $inserted_array) {
    print("ID: ".$id."\n");
    print_r($inserted_array);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
   ID: 1234
    Array
    (
        [title] => a title
        [icon] => icon-1
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => nameA
                        [desc] => a description
                        [id] => an id
                        [type] => image
                        [std] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => nameB
                        [desc] => a description
                        [id] => an id
                        [type] => image
                        [std] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```